# Create a graphical viz of list of elements residing in a column in desired order

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, markov-process, bayesian-networks

I have a list of elements in a column. Example:

### UID.................Flow

1............................qwerty, asdfgh, zxcvbn, poiuyt, lkjhgf, mnbvcx

2............................qpwoei, alskdj, zmxncb, qmwneb, zpxoci, glafhk

3............................uinbwe, cvbnfg, sfjvlr, sdfvll, sfvlas, fogjwl

UID and Flow are the column names.

Now for each UID, I want to create a graph which shows the flow like

1 - qwerty -> asdfgh -> zxcvbn -> poiuyt -> lkjhgf -> mnbvcx

Remember, if any element is repeated, it should point back to it, unlike just putting arrows in between all the elements.

So ultimately, for every UID, I should be able to see this graph which shows me the flow.

Can someone help me build the code for this? Or is there any package which we can use to create graphical viz like these? Thanks in advance.

-- Anirudh